# If $\mu\neq \nu$ then $\frac{1}{2}(\mu+\nu)$ is not ergodic

Tags: ergodic-theory

The following problem looks simple, but it seems there is more needed than just using the definition of ergodicity.

Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu, T)$ and $(X, \mathcal{F}, \nu, T)$ be two measure preserving dynamical systems. Show
that if $\mu\neq \nu$, then the measure $\rho := \frac{1}{2}(\mu+\nu)$ is not ergodic for $T$.

These are my ideas:
Suppose $T$ is ergodic. Since $\mu\neq \nu$, there is a set $A\in \mathcal{F}: \mu(A)\neq \nu(A)$, so wlog we can assume $\mu(A)<\rho(A)<\nu(A)$, whence it follows that $\rho(A)\notin\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ and hence can't be $T$-invariant. It seems like we must use that $T$-invariant sets form a $\sigma$-algebra.

Is there anyone with further ideas?

Comment: If you're looking for a good book I'd suggest "Ergodic Theory: with a view towards Number Theory" by Einsiedler and Ward. I recall seeing stronger result in there.

Comment: I already have a good book with a.o. Knopp's lemma, mixing theorems and much more ergodic theorems. There is no link, actually it is a syllabus.

Comment: It can't be an extreme point and so it can't be ergodic.

Comment: That is only true for if $T$ is continuous on a compact metric space isn't it?

Comment: Well, this theorem is a "only if" form, so one implication may be true without these conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an argument based on the pointwise ergodic theorem.  There is also a direct argument without using the ergodic theorem, which you can find (if I remember correctly) in the book of Walters, but I find the following to be more conceptual.

Suppose that $\rho$ is ergodic for $T$.  This implies that both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are ergodic as well.  Let $B\subseteq X$ be a measurable set, and consider its characteristic function $1_B(\cdot)$.  By the ergodic theorem, there exists a measurable set $Y\subseteq X$ with $\rho(Y)=1$ such that, for each $x\in Y$, the ergodic average
\begin{align}
   \overline{1_B}(x) &:=
      \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1_B(T^k x)
\end{align}
exists and satisfies $\overline{1_B}(x)=\int1_B\,\mathrm{d}\rho=\rho(B)$.
Similarly, there exists a measurable set $Y_\mu\subseteq X$ with $\mu(Y_\mu)=1$ such that $\overline{1_B}(x)=\int1_B\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\mu(B)$ for each $x\in Y_\mu$.

But $\rho(Y)=1$ implies $\mu(Y)=1$, thus $\mu(Y\cap Y_\mu)=1$. In particular, $Y\cap Y_\mu\neq\varnothing$.  Take $x\in Y\cap Y_\mu$.  We have $\rho(B)=\overline{1_B}(x)=\mu(B)$.  It follows that $\rho=\mu=\nu$.

Comment: why does $\rho$ ergodic imply both $\mu,\nu$ ergodic?

Comment: @mathworker21 If $\rho$ is ergodic, then for every $T$-invariant event $E$, either $\rho(E)=0$ or $\rho(E)=1$.  That means, either $\frac{1}{2}\mu(E)+\frac{1}{2}\nu(E)=1$ or $\frac{1}{2}\mu(E)+\frac{1}{2}\nu(E)=0$.  Since $0\leq\mu(E),\nu(E)\leq 1$, that implies that either $\mu(E)=\nu(E)=\rho(E)=1$ or $\mu(E)=\nu(E)=\rho(E)=0$.

Comment: erm... i guess i did something wrong in my head. sorry for wasting ur time with that

Comment: No worries ....